# Implicit module initialization in SICStus Prolog

Tags: module, prolog, sicstus-prolog

When I use a previously unused module `f`, the module is initialized and is known afterwards:

```
| ?- current_module(f).
no
| ?- assert(f:x).
yes
| ?- current_module(f).
yes
```

This also happens if I try to use a non-existent procedure:

```
| ?- current_module(f).
no
| ?- f:x.
! Existence error in f:x/0
! procedure f:x/0 does not exist
! goal:  f:x
| ?- current_module(f).
yes
```

As far as I can tell, two predicates behave differently: `current_predicate` and `predicate_property`.

```
| ?- current_module(f).
no
| ?- current_predicate(f:X).
no
| ?- findall(X-P, predicate_property(f:X,P), XPs).
XPs = [call(_A)-(meta_predicate call(0)),
       call(_B)-built_in,
       ...|...] ? ;
no
| ?- current_module(f).
no
```

So here's my actual question:

> Do other SICStus Prolog predicates behave like `current_predicate` and `predicate_property`? If so, which ones?